# How to disable iPad in .NET MAUI Project?

Tags: ipad, maui

I have a .NET MAUI app, and I would like to disable iPad support. How can I do that?

I couldn't find and setting in `info.plist` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "disable" iPad support if you have previously had it (an app that's already been to the store with iPad support) but if you have a new app what you can do is in your Info.plist make sure you only support iPhones:

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
    <integer>1</integer>
</array>
```